# Dialekte verstehen

Tags: dialect

Ich habe es sehr schwer, Dialekte zu verstehen, auch wenn mein DaF-Niveau sehr hoch sein sollte, und habe eine Hypothese, dass wenn ich 3 bis 4 unterschiedliche Dialekte lerne, werde ich alle anderen auch befriedigend verstehen können. Nun, die Frage ist, welche soll man dann nehmen? Einerseits könnte man da die unterschiedlichsten Varianten nehmen, etwa Luxemburgisch + Vorpommersch, aber mit dem letzten kann man leider nicht Vieles anfangen, da es so gut wie keine Materialien im Netz gibt. Ausserdem wäre es wahrscheinlich doch eine bessere Idee, einen mitteldeutschen Dialekt zu nehmen, der ein "Mittelfeld" darstellen würde. Was würden Sie vorschlagen?
[image: Anbei eine Dialektmappe Deutschlands]

Comment: Selbst Deutsch-Muttersprachler verzweifeln an entfernten Dialekten. Deshalb haben wir uns doch diese Kunstsprache *Hochdeutsch* überhaupt erst ausgedacht.

Comment: Mir ist noch nicht klar, warum Sie überhaupt verschiedene Dialekte lernen wollen. Nur so aus akademischem Interesse? - Ansonsten: Dialekte lernt man in der Regel, indem man in der Gegend, wo sie gesprochen werden, lebt. Dann lernt man sie im Alltag. - Bestimmte Radiosender können auch hilfreich sein, z.B. Bayerischer Rundfunk, Österreichischer Rundfunk, Schweizer Radio (was man dort hört ist oft Hochdeutsch mit leichtem dialektalem Einschlag, nicht eigentlich Dialekt. Es hilft aber trotzdem, sich an einige Besonderheiten der Aussprache zu gewöhnen).

Comment: PS: Es gibt einige Kabarettisten, die deutsche Dialekte (aus humoristischen Gründen) verwenden, besonders gerne Bairisch, einige Schwäbisch. Dann gibt es noch Hessisch, Sächsisch, ich vermute auch Berlinerisch und Plattdeutsch sowie Ruhrgebiets-Deutsch. Sich Stücke von diesen anzuhören, ist auch eine gute Übung.

Comment: @Janka, das stimmt zwar, aber ein (Hoch)Deutschmuttersprachler braucht viel weniger Zeit und Mühe, um einen für ihn neuen Dialekt zu verstehen. Muttersprachler haben da wirklich einen Vorsprung, und ich habe diesbezüglich, beinah ein Komplex %) Also ich erziele nicht, die Dialekte wirklich zu lernen (das wäre ja höchst unrealistisch wie unpraktisch), sondern sie  nach ein paar Tagen Übung verstehen zu können. 

Christian, die Parodien sind leider nicht immer sehr wahrheitsgetreu, und oft sprechen die absichtlich unklar, was keinesfalls hilft.

Comment: @Dan Das stimmt schon, aber wenn ich, sagen wir, in Hamburg sitze und, sagen wir, Bairisch verstehen lernen will - hättest du dann einen besseren Vorschlag, wie ich das praktischerweise anstellen könnte?

Comment: Ein Tipp wäre, sich Musik mit Texten im Dialekt anzuhören. Z.B. Haindling wenn es um Bayerisch geht. Wenn man nichts versteht, kann man sich den Text im Internet suchen. Das beschränkt die Auswahl auf Dialekte, für die eine gewisse Menge Musik existiert, wie eben Bayerisch.

Comment: @Dan  Um welche Dialekte geht es dir den konkret? Wir könnten dir vermutlich gut geeignete Künstler (Sänger, Kabarettisten, etc.) nennen, mit denen du sehr weit kommen würdest. Für **Bairisch** empfehle ich nach wie vor **Fredl Fesl**. Er singt nicht nur, sondern erzählt vor jedem Lied lang und breit etwas. Und es ist keine Imitation, sondern seine echte Alltagssprache.

Answer (score 3):

Ein Problem mit dem erlernen von Dialekten ist das zusätzliche Vokabular (Babbadegl, Kruscht). Da hilft es nicht ein paar Dialekte "repräsentativ" zu lernen. Dazu kommen noch viele Redewendungen, die nur regional verwendet werden.

Ein weiterer Punkt ist die veränderte Grammatik. Das schwäbische vermeidet z.B. den Genitiv und auch im Kölsch gibt es einige ungewöhnliche Konstrukte. siehe Texte der Band BAP.

Auch von der Aussprache her entfernen sich viele Dialekte extrem von der Hochsprache. Da wird z.B. **Grüße** zu **Griaß** oder "xi" statt "gewesen".

Eine gute Vorstellung wie extrem Dialekte abweichen können kann man bei den entsprechenden Versionen der Wikipedia erhalten, sie [alemannisch](https://als.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Houptsyte), [plattdüütsch](https://nds.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:H%C3%B6%C3%B6ftsiet) oder [boarisch](https://bar.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoamseitn)

Der einzige brauchbare Weg ist eigentlich sich über längere Zeit dem entsprechenden Dialekt auszusetzen. Die Dialekte haben ja immer ihre Eigenheiten. Das Fränkische ersetzt z.B. das **p** und **t** mit **b** und **d**.

Die Dialekte die am weitesten von der Hochsprache abweichen, sind wahrscheinlich Plattdeutsch, Kölsch, Bayerisch und Schwizerdütsch. Ich denke es brauch aber einige Monate bis man da jeweils ein Ohr dafür bekommt. Als Muttersprachler sind die Vernetzungen im Gehirn zum Erkennen von deutschen Sprachmustern wahrscheinlich besser entwickelt, aber wenn ich Kölsch höre verstehe ich auch große Teile nicht.

Wollte man sich als Nicht-Muttersprachler mit einem Dialekt näher beschäftigen, dann ist es wahrscheinlich am Besten sich mit etwas regionalem zu beschäftigen. Mit Bayerisch/Österreichisch kommt man im Süden recht weit, zwischen Thüringisch und Sächsisch kann man sich im Osten einen aussuchen, oder vielleicht einen rheinischen Dialekt im Westen und schließlich für den Norden friesisch/plattdütsch.
Das Wichtigste ist am Anfang wahrscheinlich die Schulung des Gehörs.

Answer (score 3):

Auch deutsche Muttersprachler haben ernsthafte Probleme, Dialekte zu verstehen, die in entfernteren Regionen gesprochen werden. Ich lebe z.B. im Osten Österreichs, nicht weit weg von Wien. Zu uns kommen viele Immigranten und Touristen aus den verschiedensten Regionen Deutschlands, und ich erlebe immer wieder, dass manche von ihnen richtiggehend verzweifeln, weil sie uns Einheimische nicht verstehen.

Ich war selbst vor einiger Zeit in der Schweiz, und dort ist es mir ähnlich ergangen. Wenn sich zwei Schweizer in der Straßenbahn miteinander unterhalten, verstehe ich als Ost-Österreicher genau gar nichts.

Das ist normal. Das ist nichts, worüber du dir den Kopf zerbrechen musst. Denn genau zu diesem Zweck haben wir ja das Standard-Deutsch (auch »Hochdeutsch« genannt), das jedes Kind in der Schule lernt, und das allem Menschen beigebracht wird, die Deutsch als Fremdsprache lernen.

Jeder erwachsene deutsche Muttersprachler beherrscht diesen Standard (natürlich mit den zu erwartenden Ausnahmen, die aber nicht ins Gewicht fallen).

Das heißt: Wenn du mit Deutschen, Schweizern, Österreichern, Südtirolern usw. sprichst, wird man mit dir Hochdeutsch sprechen, und ihre werdet euch gut verstehen können. Wenn du aber versuchen solltest, die Gespräche von Einheimischen zu belauschen, wirst du scheitern. Aber so geht es auch uns Muttersprachler. Willkommen im Klub!

Wenn du dich längere Zeit (mehrere Jahre) in einer bestimmten Region aufhältst, wirst du ohnehin den dort gebräuchlichen Dialekt so ganz nebenbei erlernen, und das ist auch genau der Dialekt den du im Alltag brauchen wirst.

Answer (score 3):

Es gibt hier nur selten charmante Fragen zur deutschen Sprache, aber diese ist eindeutig charmant. :-)

Wenn es dir - warum auch immer - ein Herzensanliegen ist, dich mit Regio- bzw. Dialekten vertraut zu machen, kommst du vielleicht ein Stück vorwärts, wenn du Radio hörst. Auf https://www.deutschlandfunk.de/ z.B. sind viele Beiträge nachhörbar und häufig komplett transkribiert.

Da wird also, wenn ein regionaler Einschlag zu hören ist, die hochdeutsche Fassung gleich mitgeliefert. Das könnte nützlich sein.

Vielleicht solltest du aber nicht versuchen, den einen oder anderen Regio- oder Dialekt zu lernen, sondern lediglich, Lautverschiebungen zu erkennen und das Verschobene zurückzuverschieben. Mehr können Deutschsprachige auch nicht tun.

Answer (score 2):

Ich würde mich danach richten, falls das Ihr Ziel sein sollte, wo ich hin ziehe.
Ich komme aus Berlin und bin der festen Überzeugung, dass das der beste "Dialekt" (Ich glaube es zählt offiziell als Mundart) ist! ;) 
Um ein kulturellen Einblick zu bekommen, würde ich mir die bekannteren näher Anschauen:

- Schwäbisch
- Bayrisch
- Sächsisch
- "Norddeutsch" Was auch immer das sein soll.

Das sind zumindest die meiner Meinung auch in Deutschland bekanntesten, da sie häufig parodiert oder in Film und Fersehen thematisiert werden.

Ich glaube es gibt nicht DEN Dialekt und viele Deutsche kommen gerade so mit ihrem eigenen klar.

Ich hoffe das hilft ein wenig.

und jetz'verfatz da ;)

Comment: ""Norddeutsch" Was auch immer das sein soll."
Joa, genau :D Es gibt nämlich etwa 8 grosse Dialektgruppen des Norddeutschen. 

Wie kann man sich übrigens mit Berlinisch vertraut machen?

Comment: Der Wikipediarikel zu [Berliner Dialekt](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berliner_Dialekt) beschreibt es eigentlich ganz gut. Ansonsten gibt es auch einige Lieder die in "Berlinisch" gehalten sind. Die Band "Icke und Er" (Ich und Er auf Hochdeutsch) sind da ein gutes Beispiel. [Richitg geil] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=612BH8m_Up8). Generell wird es aber nicht mehr so viel gesprochen. Ich spreche es eigentlich nur noch mit meinen Eltern in Ostberlin, gleichaltrige (~28)  sind häufig nicht aus Berlin und sprechen ihren ursprünglichen Dialekt.

Answer (score 2):

I glaub, des brengt nix, so rein deorettisch an Dialekt lerna zom wolla. Dô moss ma oifach dô lääba wo so gschwätz werd.

Ah, ônd wo mer grad derbei send: Dialekt wird braktisch blooß gschwätzt, ônd it gschrieba. Also, wenn dmii frôôgsch: Gang halt dôô naa wo dess gschprocha wird wo du moinsch dass du dees brauchsch oder wo du kääl fändsch.

Mach doch mol Urlaub em Allgai! Dô isch's eh schee!

Comment: +1 für _Dô isch's eh schee!_

Comment: Na wenn du einlädst! :D
Ik heb allet verstande, ausser "kääl" ;)